# How to read data from nodejs spawn as it is received

Tags: node.js, stream, child-process

I have a small problem with a nodejs program. I'm trying to use the `child_process` module but the following code will only trigger the `data` event once I remove my card from a nfc card reader.

The problem is that the output I need is available before the card is removed.

For example if I put my card on the reader it will take half a second to print some lines inculding the card UID.

Then if I don't release the card, the program `nfc-poll` will still be working but won't output anything. As soon as I remove my card from the reader, it will output something and then close the buffer. This is when the event `data` is emitted.

What I'd like is to be able to read every byte as soon as possible to emit the card id as soon as possible.

```
function NFCReader() {
  this.reader = new events.EventEmitter()
  this.start_process()
}

NFCReader.prototype = {
  start_process: function () {
    this._process = cp.spawn('nfc-poll', [], {})
    this._process.on('close', this.restart_process.bind(this))
    //this._process.stdout.on('data', this.handle_data.bind(this))
    this._process.stdout.readableFlowing = true
    this._process.stdout.on('data', this.handle_data.bind(this))
    this._process.stderr.on('data', this.handle_error.bind(this))
  },

  handle_data: function (data) {
    var _data = data.toString()
    var uid_lines = _data
      .split('\n')
      .filter(function (line) {return line.search('UID') >= 0})

    if (uid_lines.length != 1) {
      this.reader.emit('error', 'Multiple UID found')
      return
    }

    var card_id = uid_lines[0]
      .trim()
      .split(':')[1].trim()
      .replace(/[ ]+/g, ':')

    this.reader.emit('card', card_id)
  },
}
```

I tried to use pipe but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

this is a runStream function from my [release tools repo](https://github.com/signicode/scramjet-release-tools/blob/master/lib/index.js):

```
const stdin = input ? "pipe" : "ignore";
const out = new StringStream();
const child = execspawn(cmd, Object.assign(options, {
    stdio: [stdin, "pipe", 2]
}));

child.on("error", e => out.emit("error", e));

if (input) {
    input.pipe(child.stdin);
}
return child.stdout.pipe(out);
```

You can reproduce it or if you'd care to wait a couple days I could release it as a separate module. I guess there may already be something like that though...

Comment: From what I read it won't be of any help because the program I'm running doesn't flush its cache so the nodejs app receives data from stdin only when the process quit since the quantity of data is too small to overflow the pipe cache. The only fix I can think of is to either reduce the cache size or change the app I'm running.

Comment: Well - if it seems that way... I'd try tweaking stdbuf parameters though... That may affect system handling of pipes.